# \sum_i acts as \sum\limits_i but just sometimes

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

The code part looks like this

```
\begin{equation}
   \frac
    {
        \left(\sum_i r_{ik}x_{ij}\right) - 
        \mu'_{kj}\left(\sum_i r_{ik}\right) +
        (\alpha-1)-\mu'_{kj}(\alpha+\beta-2)
    }
    {
        \mu'_{kj}(1-\mu'_{kj}) 
    } = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \left(\sum_i r_{ik}x_{ij}\right) - 
    \mu'_{kj}\left(\sum_i r_{ik}\right) +
    (\alpha-1)-\mu'_{kj}(\alpha+\beta-2)
     = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \mu'_{kj} \left[\left(\sum_i r_{ik}\right)+\alpha+\beta-2\right] 
    = \left(\sum_i r_{ik} x_{ij}\right)+\alpha-1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \mu'_{kj} = \frac{
        \left(\sum_i r_{ik} x_{ij}\right)+\alpha-1
    }
    {
        \left(\sum_i r_{ik}\right)+\alpha+\beta-2
    }
\end{equation}
```

For the first and last equation the `\sum_i` gets rendered as it should but for the two mid-equations the `\sum_i` gets rendered as `\sum\limits_i` which doesn't look good at all.

What has happened with my code?!
The rest of the code can be found here: 
https://github.com/Jim-Holmstroem/dd2447/blob/map_first/homework/assignment2/doc.tex#L266

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a `displaystyle mathmode` vs `inline mathmode` issue.

In your particular case, it comes down to using `\sum` in a `\frac` or not. You'll notice that in your first and last equation you haven't used `\sum` inside of a `\frac`. In your middle two equations, you *have* used it inside a `\frac`.

By default, `TeX` will display a `\sum` inside of a `\frac` as `inline mode`. You can change this by using `\displaystyle` immediately before it, or (better) `\dfrac` from the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) package.

If you're in `displaystyle` mode and you want it look like `inline`, then you can use the `\textstyle` command, which is (kind of) the opposite of `\displaystyle`. For example

```
\begin{equation}
    \textstyle\sum_i
\end{equation}
```

works fine, but I'm not sure how recommendable it is :)

Comment: I'd use `\sum\limits_i` in this case.